# Align a div bottom left of an image with CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to place a price block into an existing card box.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g6bzkjvd/

My try was this one:

```
.price {
    position: absolute;
    top: -34px;
    left: 0;
    background: #e74c3c;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I would like the orange block is aligned bottom left but it doesn't work.

Could you please point me into the rights direction please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you keep image and price in same div and give position as relative. I have added a div with class name as .container-div and updated css.

```
<div class="container-div">

        <img src="https://cdn-image.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/styles/1600x1000/public/hotel-interior-room0416.jpg?itok=5gENxAK1" class="img-fluid rounded-top" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="price">229 $</div>
    </div>
```

In your csss file

```
container-div{
  position: relative;
}

.price {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:5px;
    right:0;
    background: #e74c3c;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I have updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9vcu3yLr/)

Answer (score 1):

Change `top` to `bottom` value or top: 139px; like this

```
.price {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 234px;
    left: 0;
    background: #e74c3c;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/0achp39n/6/

If you want keep postion when image change height, add wrapped div for image and price text like this
https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/0achp39n/13/

Comment: And what's happen if one day I have an image that is not the same height ?

Comment: you should wrap a div include image and price text and use bottom and left